# SQL Server 2012 IsDescendantOf SLOW

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012, hierarchyid

Let's say that the table 'Items' (about 1000 records) has the following fields:

```
ItemID (smallint, primary key)
ItemHierarchyID (HierarchyID)
ItemName (varchar(max))
```

This query (just for testing purposes) takes about 0 seconds:

```
    SELECT A.*
    FROM Items A, Items B
    WHERE A.ItemID = B.ItemID

    (output: 1011 records)
```

Instead this other takes about **25 seconds**:

```
     SELECT A.*
     FROM Items A, Items B
     WHERE A.ItemHierarchyID.IsDescendantOf(B.ItemHierarchyID) = 1

     (output: 1035 records)
```

I add that many of these records have ItemHierarchyID = NULL.

**Why IsDescendantOf is so slow?**

Comment: Voted to move to DBA.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten that Item ItemHierarchyID is a computed column. That **was** the problem. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

A breadth first index could improve your query performance. Change your table definition to this:

```
ItemID (smallint, primary key)
ItemHierarchyID (HierarchyID)
HierarchyLevel as ItemHierarchyID.GetLevel()
ItemName (varchar(max))
```

and then add the following index:

```
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX Items_Breadth_First ON Items(HierarchyLevel,ItemHierarchyID ) ;
```